# Visualizing association rules imported from a .csv file

Tags: r, plot, visualization, apriori, arules

I generated association rules using the apriori algorithm in R. Normally, I can visualize the rules generated using the code below:

```
# Load the arules package
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)

# Generate example transaction data
example_transactions <- list(
  c("item1", "item2", "item3"),
  c("item1", "item3"),
  c("item2", "item4"),
  c("item1", "item2", "item4"),
  c("item2", "item3")
)

# Convert the transaction data to a transactions object
example_transactions <- as(example_transactions, "transactions")

# Mine association rules
example_rules <- apriori(example_transactions, 
                         parameter = list(support = 0.02, confidence = 0.2),
                         control = list(verbose = FALSE))

# Plot the association rules using the "paracoord" method
plot(example_rules, method = "paracoord")
```

[image]

I exported the rules to CSV and performed a manual rule selection using the Lift Increase Criterion (LIC) since I could not do this in R. Applying the LIC criterion led to a reduction in the number of rules (LIC involves selecting rules which experience an increase - by a particular threshold - in the lift of their parent rule when a new item is added to the pre-existing item in the lhs of parent rule).

Now, I want to import the manually selected rules into R again and visualize them using plot(). However, when I do this, the code does not work properly.

```
write(example_rules,
      file = "rules.csv",
      sep = ",",
      quote = TRUE,
      row.names = FALSE)


# Read the CSV file into a data frame
rules_df <- read.csv("rules.csv")

# Create a rules object
rules <- as(rules_df, "rules")
```

The error received is"

```
Error in as(rules_df, "rules") : 
  no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “rules”
```

I also tried to convert the data frame into a transaction, but this did not work either.

```
rules_df <- read.csv("rules.csv")

rules_df <- as.data.frame(unlist(rules_df))
rules_trans <- as(rules_df, "transactions")
plot(rules_trans, method = "paracoord")
```

[image]

I noticed that the structure of the object created by the apriori function and the data frame are different. But how can I work around this and generate the plot?

```
> str(example_rules)
Formal class 'rules' [package "arules"] with 4 slots
  ..@ lhs    :Formal class 'itemMatrix' [package "arules"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ data       :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:22] 3 0 3 1 2 0 2 1 0 1 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:21] 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 4 20
  .. .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. .. ..@ itemInfo   :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ labels: chr [1:4] "item1" "item2" "item3" "item4"
  .. .. ..@ itemsetInfo:'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
  ..@ rhs    :Formal class 'itemMatrix' [package "arules"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ data       :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:20] 3 2 0 1 0 3 1 3 0 2 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:21] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 4 20
  .. .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. .. ..@ itemInfo   :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ labels: chr [1:4] "item1" "item2" "item3" "item4"
  .. .. ..@ itemsetInfo:'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
  ..@ quality:'data.frame': 20 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ support   : num [1:20] 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 ...
  .. ..$ confidence: num [1:20] 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.5 ...
  .. ..$ coverage  : num [1:20] 1 1 1 1 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.6 0.6 ...
  .. ..$ lift      : num [1:20] 1 1 1 1 0.833 ...
  .. ..$ count     : int [1:20] 2 3 3 4 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..@ info   :List of 5
  .. ..$ data         : symbol example_transactions
  .. ..$ ntransactions: int 5
  .. ..$ support      : num 0.02
  .. ..$ confidence   : num 0.2
  .. ..$ call         : chr "apriori(data = example_transactions, parameter = list(support = 0.02, confidence = 0.2), control = list(verbose = FALSE))"
> str(rules_df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ rules     : chr  "{} => {item4}" "{} => {item3}" "{} => {item1}" "{} => {item2}" ...
 $ support   : num  0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 ...
 $ confidence: num  0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.5 ...
 $ coverage  : num  1 1 1 1 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.6 0.6 ...
 $ lift      : num  1 1 1 1 0.833 ...
 $ count     : int  2 3 3 4 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
```

**Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? I would immensely appreciate your support.**

Answer (score 0):

Once rules are written in a human-readable form using `write()`, then they cannot be easily read back in since lots of information is lost. One option is to use PMML instead (see `write.PMML`). However, the result is an XML file which you cannot use in Excel.

It is easy to filter using LIC in package `arules`.

```
example_rules[!is.redundant(example_rules, measure = "lift")]
```

Will remove all rules with LIC <= 1. It technically uses improvement, but that has the same effect.